# Authentication not working after editing Cookie options

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity

In have controller-methods for ajax-request with an authorize attribute. When I make a request when I'm not logged in, I get a redirect to the login page. I need an Unauthorized and not the Login page data. To change this I overridden the "OnRedirectToLogin" event.

Here is the Code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = ctx => Test(ctx);
        });


private Task Test(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> ctx)
    {
        if (ctx.Request.ContentType != null && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            if (ctx.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

All changes work, but when I try to log in on the default login-page, nothing happens.

What is the Problem there or have you a better option to achieve the same result without this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Update:
I've kept looking in the time since the post has been online. Now I have found out that the login works, but the authentication on the controller apparently no longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation I have found this solution:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
            {
                if (ctx.Request.ContentType != null && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    if (ctx.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
                    {
                        ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

The decisive factor was to set only the  "DefaultChallengeScheme"